# Perché si usa l'espressione "avere gli occhi sbarrati"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, phrase-origin

"Avere gli occhi sbarrati" è una notissima espressione d'uso comune. L'aggettivo "sbarrato" viene inteso nel senso di "spalancato", come si puó trovare su qualsiasi dizionario.

Tuttavia, in altri contesti, "sbarrato" indica esattamente l'opposto di "spalancato", ovvero "chiuso", "inaccessibile", "tagliato fuori".

Come è nata questa espressione e come mai, in questo caso, si usa un aggettivo che comunemente vuol dire una cosa per indicare l'esatto contrario?

**Addendum**

In seguito alla prima risposta ed a qualche commento, vorrei aggiungere che la mia domanda vale anche in senso opposto. Perché oggi diciamo "sbarrare la strada" se generalmente la "s" come suffisso ha valore privativo?

Comment: L'usava già [Dante](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Divina_Commedia/Inferno/Canto_VIII): "per ch’io avante l’occhio intento sbarro" (*Inferno* VIII, 66).

Comment: Curiosamente, ho trovato nell'[*Enciclopedia Dantesca Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sbarro_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) che Dante ha anche usato "sbarro" in *Purgatorio* XXXIII 42 ("secure d'ogn'intoppo e d'ogne sbarro") col senso di "impedimento", "ostacolo".

Answer (score -1):

S-barrare è usato come togliere la barra (che tiene chiuso), quindi aprire.

Si veda [qui](http://www.etimo.it/?term=sbarrare&find=Cerca)

Comment: È probabile che ci sia del vero, ma sarebbe bene trovare altre fonti, visto che il Pianigiani è vecchio e soprattutto un po' fantasioso (vedi [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online/1202#1202)) e che questo significato non si trova in altri dizionari.

Comment: @DaG: Infatti appare in questo [*Vocabolario universale italiano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=bsPBk-PG48AC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=sbarrare+barra&source=bl&ots=63hw4k7_kl&sig=ACfU3U3tML_FGq4ZGpmFfFPX5rVa7Xd79w&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR193GpM3gAhUITBoKHf1kDgcQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=sbarrare%20barra&f=false) dell'Ottocento nel quale si legge "da *S* privativo, e da *barra*".